# How to do Free hand Image Cropping in WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

all
I m developing on Medical Image Processing software, I wont crop image on mouse event, means when we drag mouse cursor and move over the image in any shape, the selected portion of image should be cropped. and that will paste in same image. is it Possible in WPF or Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Clip property. You can specify a path in this property that is used to clip the parent object. Set Clip on your Image control to clip the image.

For design time clipping, your best bet is to use Blend (download a trial [here](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx) if you don't have it) to draw a free hand path. Right click on the path and select Path->Make Clipping Path. In the next dialog, select the image that you want to clip.

**EDIT:** It sounds like you want to use runtime clipping/cropping, so you will want to generate the clip path using the points gathered from the mouse events. Create a collection of these points and then generate a path from them (linear lines probably... I don't know how you would generate appropriate curves unless you wrote a complex algorithm). Set this path to the Clip property after the fact.
**/EDIT**

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your question fully. You probably can't use Blend for this because you are doing cropping/clipping at runtime. Blend would be for design time clipping. Editing answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a transparent layer on top of the control and add an InkCanvas.

Then allow the user to draw a stroke (freehand) and turn the stroke into a Geometry by using `GetGeometry` use the geometry in the Clip property of the control to be clipped.